# creating dynamic links

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I need to create a link that will look like following

```
 =CONCATENATE("http://servernaem/SMSReporting/Report.asp?ReportID=104&AdvertID=SCCM20067&Name=", A5)
```

The problem is when I click the link, the data from `A5` is missing. (It does appear in the Excel spreadsheet.

What would be a preferred solution is to have the work Status Report appear in the cell instead of the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put your concatenate into a hyperlink function.

`=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://servernaem/SMSReporting/Report.asp?ReportID=104&AdvertID=SCCM20067&Name=", A5))`

A better way to concatenat two strings is with the `&` character like this

`=HYPERLINK("http://servernaem/SMSReporting/Report.asp?ReportID=104&AdvertID=SCCM20067&Name="& A5)`